# Floating div won't align to the left in a responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have ASP:REPEATER (dynamic list) with floating divs to the left that looks like this:

```
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +---------------------+
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | +---------------------+
|                     | |                     | +---------------------+
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ |                     |
                                                |                     |
                                                |                     |
                                                |                     |
                                                +---------------------+
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +---------------------+
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +---------------------+
```

But the 4th div is supposed to apear in another line no matter the height of the 3rd one. The problem is that I have a responsive design so I can't give it a specific height. It should be looking like this:

```
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +---------------------+
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | +---------------------+
|                     | |                     | 
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ 
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +---------------------+
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
|                     | |                     | |                     |
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +---------------------+
+---------------------+
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

Here's the class of each div:

```
.wrapProducts
{
float: left; width: 30%;
margin: 0% 3% 5% 0%;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need to use `float` or can you declare them as `inline`&`inline-block`?

Comment: Use Bootstrap and the Bootstrap Row/Col placement

Comment: use clear:left; (CSS) after every third element (pseudo selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `float` in this situation, what is happening is the normal behavior of `float`. [Read this CSS-Tricks article for more infos.](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). You can `clear` every third elements but then your layout won't be responsive anymore.

You only have two responsive solutions to achieve your list layout:

You can either use a **table layout** with `table`, `tr` and `td`, or you can use **`inline-block` divs** instead of floating divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using clear:both on the styling of the final div.

If you remove the final div do you otherwise achieve your design?

Comment: Please read : [answer]. StackOverflow is a Q&A, not a forum. So you shouldn't ask another question in your answer ;) If you need any details, ask them in comments ;)